# Send form data to Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The problem is that when I run this my real-time database is not updating and there are no errors coming or showing.

```js
function writeData() {
    firebase.database().ref("user").set( {
            Email: document.getElementById("help").value,
            Price: document.getElementById("price1").value,
            Desc: document.getElementById("Pdesc").value,
        }

    );
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Enter Product name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="help" aria-describedby="emailHelp">

    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Product Price</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price1">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Product description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Pdesc">
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" id="upProgess" class="form-label">Upload a file</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="namebox">
                </div> -->
    <button type="submit" onclick="writeData()" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: have you set firebase app correctly https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?sdk_version=v8 in your javascript code?

Comment: yes i have set firebase correctly i just need to make sure that is this code correct ?? and if it is then why is it that it's not working

Comment: @Ibadhussain Have you linked your web app to your firebase project and loaded the firebase JS SDK correctly? Sometimes this doesn't work when your firebase script versions don't match.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your realtime firebase, sometimes if you use free, your realtime firebase has expired (for 1 month).
You can print it by inputting a simple value, for example:

If nothing happens, then check your project's API, library, or expiration date.

Solution:
Create a new project.

Comment: my firebase project is created recently  and it's working I created a simple label and integrated with firebase but my website form is not working